# Implementation issue in cascading while reading data from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, cascading, bigdata

Suppose I have these files in `hdfs` directory

```
500/Customer/part-001
500/Customer/part-002
500/Customer/part-003
```

Can it be possible to check from which **part file** the tuple is coming?

Note:I have researched but got nothing.

Comment: add example/sample tuple, and  data from these file. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is not very clear.
Let's say your output is in following layout and the delimiter is ';'

id;name;age

1;Jordan;22

2;Nathan;33

and so on

You could use awk or grep or both to get the record

for example, if you want to search for the record Nathan, try the file command

grep -r "Nathan" part*

above command will search for the string "Nathan" and if the string is present in any part file then the first entry (word) in output will be the name of the file.

if you don't want the file name you could use

grep -hr "Nathan" part*

Please be more clear when questioning.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer how to get from which part file tuple file are coming.I solved my problem using code below.

> ```
> String fileName = flowProcess.getProperty("cascading.source.path").toString();
> ```

Thanks,